# Excel not calculating a hh:mm formula where part of formula is derived from anothe formula result

Tags: excel-formula

Am attempting to convert 11 hrs and 27 minutes to minutes but receiving incorrect results.

I am working on an application that charges a fee for parking of aircraft. The charges are levied on a per 5 minute basis. I have an aircraft that is parking for 11hrs and 27 minutes. This value is derived from another formula. I am trying to break that down to minutes so I can divide the total minutes by 5 in order to arrive at a total billable 5 minute periods. That is not working unless I direct input the 11hrs and 27 minutes and unless I do that I am getting 25,124,682 as a results. Trying different formats produces different incorrect results.

Cell B3 and B5 have arrival and departure dates as follows:

B3 02 06 19 17:18 formatted as dd mm yy\ hh:mm

B5 03 06 19 18:09 formatted as dd mm yy\ hh:mm

Cell D3 has the total parking time OF 11:27 Mins derived from adding cells B3 and B5 together and formatted as hh:mm.
Cell G3 has a value of 5 minutes (being that for every 5 minutes a charge is raised) formatted as mm:ss. I have tried all different combinations of the format but it all boils down to the 11H27 minutes coming from a formula

I am expecting a result of 137.4 but receiving 25,124,682 unless I direct input the time value of 11hrs and 27 minutes.

Comment: Apologies.. my formula is =D3*1440/G3. If anyone has any ideas to why this is happening I would really appreciate a heads up as it is me stumped for three days. My guess is that it turns out to be a really simple issue but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.. thanks in advance all..

Comment: What is the formula in D3? B3+B5 or B5-B3? Did you notice that your two times are a day apart? base on those two dates the arrival and departure time in your example the time at the gate is 24:51 (hh:mm)

Answer (score 1):

There are more than 24 hours from `02 06 19 17:18` to `03 06 19 18:09`.

You need to subtract those values, instead of "adding":

```
= B5-B3
```

The result will be given in (fractions of) days. Basic mathematics will get to your result.

See the screenshot below. The formulas are the ones used on line `2`.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Virolio.. can you tell me what formats you are using and how important they are? I ran the same calculation on a 2hr time frame and instead of getting 24  five minute periods I got 576. time and date calculations do my head in but they are critical to aviation :) Why I ask about formatting is because the results are accurate when I format as 'general' ..I was under the impression that all date / time calculations should have the same formatting else things could awry.. Here I see that that is not so.. but going forward I will have to see how I go..

Comment: I used the standard Excel notation for dates / times. They are very important, otherwise Excel will not know how to manipulate the information.